# How do I calculate the work done on the box?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, work

A 2 kg box with some initial velocity slides up a ramp, which is at a 15 degree angle to the ground, until the box comes to rest 1 second later. The coefficient of friction is 0.2.

How much work is done on the box? Solve using energy and forces methods – compare results.

I tried doing this by myself, but I keep getting mixed up and getting different answers from both methods. Can you show me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site does not accept answers that provide complete solutions to problems, but the following should help.  I believe the problem wants you to treat the box and the ramp as rigid bodies, in which case there is no change in their internal energy (i.e., no "heating" effects).  For this case, the work done by friction contributes to the change in the kinetic energy (of the center of mass) of the box.  There is no rotational energy of the box since it slides.  Since the box is sliding, the force of friction is constant.

You have two constant forces acting on the box: gravity and the force of friction.  You can calculate the work done on the box by the forces from the force/distance relationship, keeping in mind the proper signs.

With no "heating" you know the relationship for energy considering kinetic and potential energy, and you can relate the change in energy to the work done by the force of friction (the work done by gravity is accounted for as change in potential energy).

What is the "skater" in your question; do you mean "box"?

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! Yes I meant box, sorry about that!

Comment: You are welcome.